# Is there a way to create a dockable palette for Photoshop with ScriptUI?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, photoshop-scripting

I am using ScriptUI for the first time and would like to create a custom palette with several text boxes and buttons that can be conveniently docked into the Photoshop UI.

Can this be accomplished using a script?

Comment: A quick search for "scriptui dockable palette" yielded [this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1034640) - it's for InDesign but should apply to Photoshop as well. And just as a heads up, questions that are more about _how_ to script something might end up being closed as off-topic. As you learn Adobe scripting, you might be better served at Stack Overflow or the Adobe forums (although if the moderators were okay with scripting questions being answered here, I'd be okay with that too!).

Comment: @Brendan thanks for the link, so it seems that this is not possible without using Extension Builder or by implementing a custom plugin using C++.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be possible. Only thing you can do is set type of window. Some type of window block interaction with Photoshop and some not. It won't be dockable. For dockable palete you need to create HTML panel and that is a lot of work.